# Proper definition of concyclic?

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, complex-numbers

Let $z_1,z_2...,z_n$ be points in the complex plane, then if there exists $Z$ such that $$\vert Z-z_k\vert=a\in\{\text{Real Numbers}\}$$for all $k\in \{1, 2, 3...,n\}$, then $z_1,z_2...,z_n$ are concyclic. Is this a proper definition of concyclicity?

Comment: Provided that you're clear that the same $Z$ and $a$ apply across all $z_k$, then: yes, this is a proper definition.

Comment: In the complex plane, it often makes sense to include lines as special cases of circles. That's because Möbius transformations map lines and circles to lines and circles. Your definition doesn't cover lines. Which might be what you want, just be aware of the fact that other definitions are somtimes being used, e.g. $$\frac{(z_1-z_3)(z_2-z_4)}{(z_1-z_4)(z_2-z_3)}\in\mathbb R$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\exists Z\in\mathbb C:\exists a\in\mathbb R:\forall k\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}:
\lvert Z-z_k\rvert=a$$

is indeed a valid definition of cocircularity. It's pretty straight-forward: you ask whether there is a center $Z$ and a radius $a$ such that the points lie on the circle defined by these two.